# Next js router and useRouter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-router

```
import { router } from "next/client";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

const CustomComponent = () => {
  const routerFromHook = useRouter();
}

export default CustomComponent;
```

What is difference between `router` object and `routerFromHook` object? Which is better?

Comment: Well, it depends on whether you want routing to occur on the client or not?

Comment: On the client side

Answer (score 0):

First line of this documentation https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/use-router says that the `useRouter` is to be used inside a functional component when the `router` object is needed.